# Using an instance variable as the value of a hidden_field? RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, instance-variables, hidden-field

im in the process of creating a form that then creates a user and sends out a generated password in an email. I'm using devise, for reference. The password must be "random" as directed, so `SecureRandom.base58(8)` is how I will be generating the password.

My thought process so far is to generate the variable inside the create action of the users controller, like so - `@generated_pass = SecureRandom.base58(8)`
and then call that variable inside the view.

The field I'm unable to get working is:
`<%= f.hidden_field :password, class: 'form-control', value: @generated_pass %>`
The form works when I enter an acceptable string (1 number, 1 capital at least) as the `value:` so I know it's not the form breaking, the problem I get when submitting with this variable is a rollback with no other information.

Have I declared the variable wrong? Should I create a method and then somehow call that method as the value? Additionally, I've tried -
`<%= f.hidden_field :password, class: 'form-control', value: SecureRandom.base58(8) %>` to no avail.

Any advice would be welcome, thankyou.
Rails -v 5.0.7.2 | Ruby -v 2.6.4

Comment: Why don't you allow the user to choose a password? That is the default way, therefore less confusing and ist is more secure, because you do not send a password via unencrypted email and allow the user to use complex passwords and password managers?

Comment: Don't generate a password and mail it out. Send the user a time limited token that they can use to reset their password or claim a premade account. But you most likely don't need to reinvent the wheel, look into [`Devise::Invitable`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) instead.

Comment: Try to check the log when you submit the form. Maybe you've some validations for `password`.

Comment: @spickermann I am working to a specification I don't get to make these decisions, this system already has the default sign up method but requires this for representatives creating accounts for their clients.

Comment: @emu Thanks, the only validations are one capital and one number must be in the password, which SecureRandom.base58(8) gives.

Comment: @max Thanks, I'm working as directed so it must be done this way, I will look into that though.

Comment: @ethanmclark, if you're creating an User with this form, and if you're using Devise gem for this - then you must provide `password_confirmation` field too. like: `<%= f.hidden_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', value: @generated_pass %>` 
Otherwise, please check logs.

Comment: Check if you can actually get the stakeholders / your boss to not do this in a very insecure way. "Hey, we could also solve this in way that's much better for our users and will be easier to implement..."

Comment: @emu `:password_confirmation` is not required, as I said if I enter a string as the value, e.g. "Password1" the form submits. The issue is purely to do with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **before_save** or **before_validation** callbacks on you model ?

This type of data should not be modified or altered in the view or controller.

Something like this in your User model:

```
before_validation :do_before_validation

def do_before_validation
    self.password = SecureRandom.base58(8) unless self.password.present?
end
```